# HTML5 Form Make Postrequest and call Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I have a simple form that makes an post request to an .php script like the code below.

```
        <form action="checkout.php" method="POST">
           <input id="orderemail" name="customer" required type="email" size="30" maxlength="50">
           <button id="ppbutton" type="submit"><img src='images/icon/pp_button2.gif' alt='Jetzt bezahlen'/></button>
        </form>
```

My Question is : Is it possible to call the post request and on the same time to call a javascript function? So the function should only be called then the input field is valid and the post request was send ! I want to use "spin.js" to create a spinner while the script on the server is working, because at the end of the script the person is forwarded to paypal.

Thanks so much ;) !

Comment: Yes, this is possible. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: tried out only href in the form and in the button ... but found out that it will work with onsubmit in the form !

Answer (score 0):

Oh i am such an idiot :P simple solution using

```
<form action="checkout.php" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:spin('ppbutton')">
```

Tried it only with href :(